# Подключение библиотеки к проекту С++ с помощью CMake

Tags: c++, cmake, библиотеки

У меня есть библиотека Graphviz уже собранная как я понимаю. Лежит в "C:\Program Files (x86)\Graphviz2.38"
Выглядит как то так:

```
{bin
etc
include
lib
    release
        lib
        dll
fonts}
```

В include лежат заголовки, а в lib и dll библиотеки.(их там много)
Мне нужно подключить её к своему проекту с++.  Я написал

```bash
include_directories("C:/Program Files (x86)/Graphviz2.38/include")
```

, чтобы проект видел заголовки. И теперь я не понимаю как сделать так, чтобы программа видела реализации этих заголовков. Я пытался подключить хотя бы одну, но даже так не работает

Как пытался сделать я:

```
add_library(XXX SHARED IMPORTED)
set_property(TARGET XXX PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION "C:/Program Files (x86)/Graphviz2.38/lib/release/dll/gvc.dll")
target_include_directories(XXX INTERFACE "C:/Program Files (x86)/Graphviz2.38/include")
target_link_libraries(EM_project PRIVATE XXX)
```

Comment: Почти угадали, в `target_library_directories` - пути к библиотекам, по аналогии с инклюдами. В `target_link_libraries` - названия. Ну и еще следует убедиться, что библиотеки собраны совместимым компилятором с совместимыми настройками, что и ваш проект.

Comment: При составлении вопроса немного не правильно написал. Сейчас поменял. Вот при таких условиях почему может не работать ?